# Iterating over XML DOM documents in standard Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xerces

Is there a direct substitute in standard `Java` (`J2SE`) 6 (no `JDOM` or other third party libraries) for the [Apache Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/) `XML DOM` document parsing and iterating classes? Using the `Sun` `J2SE` `XML` implementation, i.e.,

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeIteratorImpl
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser
```

causes warnings by the compiler that each use of these classes "is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release".

The code I currently use for instantiating a generic `NodeIterator` object is

```
org.w3c.dom.Document document = ...; // Get an XML DOM Document object

org.w3c.dom.NodeIterator iterator = new NodeIteratorImpl(new DocumentImpl(
    document.getDoctype()), document.getDocumentElement(),
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL, null, true);
```

The `NodeIterator` visits the nodes of an `XML DOM` document in depth-first search order, which is essential for my application and so the above code needs to be replaced with something functionally equivalent.

Also, would the best (= standard and fastest) way of creating a new `org.w3c.dom.Document` object be something like

```
Document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder.parse(source)
```

where `source` is a properly instantiated `org.xml.sax.InputSource` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NodeIterator` is part of the DOM traversal spec.  You can check whether a particular `Document` supports traversal by [testing whether it is an instanceof `org.w3c.dom.traversal.DocumentTraversal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/dom/org/w3c/dom/traversal/DocumentTraversal.html) (the standard implementation in the JRE should be).  If so, you can cast it and do

```
NodeIterator ni = ((DocumentTraversal)document).createNodeIterator(
      document.getDocumentElement(), NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL, null, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the (already accepted) answer to the NodeIterator part of the question. If you have time, please edit to add a comment for the seconds part that I have added, i.e. Document object instantiation.

Comment: `DocumentBuilderFactory` and `DocumentBuilder` provide the standard way to get `Document` instances. Use the `parse` methods to parse existing XML documents, and `newDocument()` to create an empty `Document`